# calling max and swap functions from a recursive backwards selection sort function

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion, max, swap

Homework: I need to write a recursive backwards selection sort function, using no loops, that calls a supplied `swap` function and `find_Max` function (just called max here) that have different parameters.

To drive `swap`, I need the index of the `max` value; I have no idea how to get that.  Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to change any parameters to `swap` nor `Max` nor `back_rec_sort`.  The first function is the problem; the other two must be called.  Also, backwards sort means find the largest value, swap it into position n-1, and then work towards 0 index.

```
//Updated version calling linear search from back_rec_sort as hw question 
does not restrict that.  

void rec_ssort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int last = n -1;

    if (last >= 0)
    {
        int Max = max(arr, 0, last);
        //int index=binarySearch(arr, 0, last, Max);
        int index = search(arr, last, Max);
        swap(arr, index, last);
        rec_ssort(arr, n - 1);
    }
    else
        return;
}

// Linearly search x in arr[].  If x is present then return its 
// location,  otherwise return -1
int search(int arr[], int n, int x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == x)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int max(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
    //Base case when there is only 1 element left
    if (start == end)
    {
        return arr[start];
    }

    //Compute middle element position  
    int m = (start + end) / 2;

    //Calling the same function with reduced size  
    int left_max = max(arr, start, m);
    int right_max = max(arr, m + 1, end);

    //Combining solutions  
    if (left_max > right_max)
    {
        return left_max;
    }
    else
    {
        return right_max;
    }
}

void swap(int arr[], int i, int j)
{
    int temp;
    temp =arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem.  If you simply return the index of the largest element, instead of the value, doesn't that fix your problem?

Comment: "_wish I knew how to find this_" well instead of returning the maximum value in `max(arr, 0, n -= 1)`, return its index !

Comment: @KyleKhalaf unfortunately we have to use the max and swap functions as is.  No changes allowed.

Comment: @Prune, please see above.  It's impossible right?

Comment: In that case, I believe you're stuck with a bit of redundant work: given that maximum value, you'd have to search the array to find its location.

Comment: @Prune that's interesting.  put a recursive binary search function inside the recursive sort function.

Comment: Interesting ... but wasteful.  Also, note that you can't depend on a binary search, since that requires the list to be sorted before it saves you time.  In this application, you're using the search to drive the sorting function.  Do a linear search, instead.

Comment: @Prune I have no idea how to put any type of search function into the back_rec_sort function.

Comment: [linear search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search) -- this would be a few lines added to your current code.

Comment: @Prune my abilities limit me to calling a linear search from within back_rec_sort but I am getting garble (the memory address?) between indexes 1 and 2, ie. {7,9,6,5,4,8} is sorted as {5,6,garble,7,8,9}.

Comment: It looks like your linear search is correct.  This is something to trace with a debugger or some simple `print` statements.  You need to figure out *when* `4` turns into `garble`; a little more work will likely show you *why*.  It helps if you publish the garble; some of us recognize certain flavours of hexadecimal mush.  My guess is that you overstepped the array bound somewhere, and grabbed an address from some other memory location.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: @Prune, thanks for the link to the blog.  Here is the error for now while I debug:  https://www.screencast.com/t/Q6FCPkmdDF

Comment: @Prune I found the problem.  After the array is sorted after the 3rd recursion, it keeps going and then search returns -1 rather than 2 which is the index of the sorted item.  Here is the link:  https://www.screencast.com/t/ubhtDeqf6XCf.  I have to figure out a way to stop the recursion once sorted or debug search.

Comment: Note that the recursion logic doesn't *know* that the array is sorted; it's trying to go through all 6 iterations (although you need only 5).  Looking at your output, it appears that the error comes when the largest element is already in the final position.  Perhaps you need to expand your linear search by one element?

Comment: @Prune, thanks for the push in the right direction.  I took out the return -1 in the search function and it works fine.

Comment: Good work!  Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing this up so we can archive the question ...

(1) Write a linear search function that takes the array and a value, then returns the index of that value in the array.

```
int search(int arr[], int n, int target)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == target)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;   // if not found
}
```

(2) The -1 failure return results in array access out of bounds -- this is a coordination problem between the original code and the search function.  Removing that line returns NULL instead, which results int he desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements of the homework, as stated in the original post, did not restrict calling an additional function so I added a linear search function to the program, called it from within back_rec_sort.  However, I kept getting a hexadecimal garble in the array, as linked in comments, so I debugged as suggested by Prune, deleted the "return -1" from the search function and it works.  I would like to learn more about how to determine corner cases for testing, debugging and on writing assertions.